# How can I make a list into a dictionary?New to python

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I make a list of strings like

```
[['Tom', '3.5'], ['Bob', '3.9'], ['Ed', '2.7'], ...]
```

into a dictionary so it only shows the names?

```
'Tom', 'Bob', 'Ed',
```

Comment: What do you mean by "only shows the names"?

Comment: uh I mean so it returns the keys, ie 'Tom'

Comment: It's unclear if you actually want a dictionary or not. Is the goal to extract the names? That has little to do with switching to a dictionary.

Comment: are you saying you would like something like {'Tom': '3.5', 'Bob', '3.9'}?

Answer (score 1):

```
my_dict = dict(my_list_of_string_pairs)
print my_dict.keys()
```

or perhaps if you just want the names in a list

```
names,scores = zip(*my_list_of_string_pairs)
```

Comment: or `[x[0] for x in pair_list]` or something like that to ignore the scores.

Comment: I wouldn't call the new variable `dict`.

Comment: dang what a rookie move :P fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got you right, but for example if you have list named `li` you can use

```
''.join(li)
```

- it creates string from list and puts after every word, except last one, the string which is inside of ''.

But in your case if you want to have only names, you can do following:
Lets say your list is named `li`

```
li2 = [li[i[0]] for i in range(len(li))]
print(li2)
```

- it creates another list named `li2` which in your case has only names and then prints it

Comment: `li2 = [item[0] for item in li]` makes alot more sense than the range thing ... doing range in python is almost always not the ideal solution.  and the first example wont work since its a list of lists ... not a list of strings

Comment: yes, its actually almost the same thing, both loops are iterating through list, but for beginners yours is easier to understand

Comment: lol for the whole world mine is easier to understand :P ... and im pretty sure its faster too

Comment: xD okay you won, but dont know which one is faster cause python optimises code

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dictionary of names: numbers, you can just pass your list to the `dict` constructor:

```
my_list = [['Tom', '3.5'], ['Bob', '3.9'], ['Ed', '2.7'], ...]
grades = dict(my_list)
```

Now `grades.keys()` is the names, `grades.values()` is the numbers, and `grades.items()` is the original list (albeit with tuples inside instead of sub-lists). Note that the ordering of the names in the original list *will not* be preserved.

If instead you just want the names from the original list, you can extract them with a simple list comprehension:

```
names = [name for name, number in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension in Python 3:

```
my_list = [['Tom', '3.5'], ['Bob', '3.9'], ['Ed', '2.7']]
my_dict = {x[0]: x[1] for x in my_list}
print(my_dict.keys())
```